# CORS: How to secure a Facebook Leadgen Webhook?

Tags: facebook, express, facebook-graph-api, cors, webhooks

I have build an Express.js app which works as a webhook for Facebook's lead-data and is subscribed to subcribed to the leadgen event.

***My question***
How can I secure this webhook so it's only accessible by Facebook directly and not by any other origin.

I've tried this with the cors-module but any attempts to setup the whitelisted origins ('http://facebook.com', 'https://facebook.com') did fail.
I suspect that Facebook doesn't include this URL in the Headers but uses very dynamic origins.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: CORS is a client-side thing, webhooks are server-to-server. You simply want to verify the SHA-1 signature Facebook sends with any notification playload, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started#validate-payloads

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps a lot! If you post this as a answer on this question, I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CORS is a client-side thing, webhooks are server-to-server - so not applicable here to begin with.]

You simply want to verify the SHA-1 signature Facebook sends with any notification playload - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started#validate-payloads:

> We sign all Event Notification payloads with a SHA1 signature and include the signature in the request's `X-Hub-Signature` header, preceded with `sha1=`. You don't have to validate the payload, but you should.